# SQL find missing records with a join on null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "`containers`" which contains a parent_id clause that specifies a hierarchy.

```
TABLE containers {
    id
    parent_id
    name
}
```

Since foreign keys were not setup I am trying to find parent containers that have been removed without updating the child to tell them to set parent_id to `NULL`.

```
SELECT * FROM container c
RIGHT JOIN container c2 ON c2.parent_id = c.id
WHERE c.id IS NULL AND c2.parent_id IS NOT NULL
```

What is the correct query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably want to do something like this (provided id is a PK or NOT NULL):

```
SELECT
  parents.id
FROM
  container children
    LEFT JOIN
  container parents ON (parents.id = children.parent_id)
WHERE
  parents.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Almost, but some "parents" also have a NULL parent_id since they are the root container.

Comment: That will not be a problem in this case :). A problem would be if "id" could be NULL.